# Please help in resolving this null pointer exception. This projct involves with struts2, jsp, java and struts.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts

The following jsp displays 4 text fields from the corresponding data base

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts2-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is for fun</p>


<s:form action="eAction" name="eSites">
    <s:textfield value="%{l.Name}" label="Name" id="name" ></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield value="%{l.plan}" label="t Plan" id="plan" ></s:textfield>

</s:form>

<s:form action="updateAction" name="eSite">

<button onclick="output()">Update</button>
<script>
function output(){
         eSite.submit();    
    }
</script>
</s:form>


</body>
</html>
```

Following is the database:

```
INSERT INTO engagement(PId, S_Id, P_Name, Pa_Plan, Pa_Method, PDate) 
    VALUES(2, 1, 'erferef', 'ergregre', 'egregref', '2012-9-19');
```

Followign is the struts.xml code.

```
    <action name="eAction"   class="com.fr.actions.EEngagement">
        <result name ="resultedfunc">/jsp/EParentEngagement.jsp</result> 
    </action>

    <action name="updateAction" class="com.fr.actions.EEngagement" method="update">
        <result name ="UPDATE">/jsp/Engagement.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

The problem arises is when I give xxx.eAction, I could see 4 text fields with data populated from db. After that if I click update button(code for this button is present in jsp file), the url is updateAction.action and I get null pointer exception in the following line.

```
        System.out.println(li.gett_Name());
```

Could some one please resolve this. I have spent almost 6+ hrs. I have tried autogenerating getters and setters and refactoring everything. But still I could not figure out. Please Please help me.

Comment: Where do you call the setListSiteDetails method? If it is not called, then the variable will remain null.

Comment: Thank you very much for replyign and helping. May I know like how to do that? Should I call the setListSiteDetails method inside the update method of java file or should I also mention the class namein the form tag of jsp. Please help me. I must set the newly modified fields data to the object.

Comment: Did you get solve your older question?Looks like you have posted  entirely  new question, and it is not supposed to change the entire context of the question especially there are answers and comments for the first question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like below operation missing in your update method

```
EditParentEngagementDAO editParentEngagementDAO = new EditParentEngagementDAO();
listSiteDetails = editParentEngagementDAO.aSiteIdDetails(getParentengid());
```

You may need to call this before calling `listsitedetails.get..`